SocketIO: what is the practical approach to deliver the messages from the server side
I'm implementing the chat with Flask-Socketio and React+socket.io. I found the react socket changes its id occasionally and if it happens while the server is handling the response, the server message is never delivered.
What is a good, practical approach to delivering messages and how can it be implemented if the server doesn't know a new socket id? But even if the server knows it, I have no idea how to send it exactly to the new socket instance. And how to provide it for all tabs opened in the same browser?
Here is my code in React:
    const init = ()=>{
        const socketInstance = io(wsUrl, {
            autoConnect: false,
        });
        setSocket(socketInstance);
        socketInstance.on('message', (data) => {
            if (data.message){
                setOperatorMessage(data.message); // Receiving message
            }
        });
    };
...
    const sendUserMessage = async()=>{
        if (!socket.connected){
            socket.connect();
        }
        socket.emit('message', {data: {message: userMessage}}); 
    } 


And here is the Flask code:
@socketio.on('message', namespace='/ws')
def receive_message(message_data):
    # Handling, generating the response
    emit('message', {'result': True, 'message': chat_message})

    return


What do you mean with "the react socket changes its id occasionally"? As long as the web socket connection is live, both parties can talk to each other. There are no "id" values involved?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Honestly, I don't know why it happened. Maybe the socket disconnected, then connected again, and here is a new id.
